# How to center objects in parent with Dock Fill VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, max, dock

I'm trying to make a RichTextBox have fixed size and blank space flexible (like Word, WordPad), I made this:

Set `Dock` to `Fill`
Set `MaximumSize` to `600,0` (0 is wildcard for sizes) (Width=600 and Height=0 -wildcard)

I got this: blank spaces are flexible and RichTextBox size is fixed, but RichTextBox is not positioned at center.

I have some options:

- Set padding to auto (I suppose that it's not possible)
- Set margin to auto (I suppose that it's not possible AND margins not works in winforms)

What do I have to do to position RichTextBox to center?

Comment: Use the Anchor property instead, turn on the Right and Bottom anchors.  Not every conceivable layout arrangement is practical with the built-in layout control properties or the TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel controls, tricky once require code.  Use the form's Resize event to put it where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `anchor` instead of `dock`.

> Dock is designed for Size, Anchor is designed for Location

Your problem is based on location, locate your box to center instead of make `Dock` margins.